# TypeError: Can't convert re.compile('[A-Z]+') (re.Pattern) to Union[str, tokenizers.Regex]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm having issues applying a Regex expression to a `Split()` operation found in the HuggingFace Library. The [library](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/api/reference.html#module-tokenizers.pre_tokenizers) requests the following input for `Split()`.

> pattern (str or Regex) – A pattern used to split the string. Usually a
> `string` or a `Regex`

In my code I am applying the `Split()` operation like so:

```
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Split(pattern="[A-Z]+", behavior='isolated')
```

but it's not working because `[A-Z]+` is being interpreted as  a string not a Regex expression. I've used the following to no avail:

```
pattern = re.compile("[A-Z]+")
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Split(pattern=pattern, behavior='isolated')
```

Getting the following error:

> TypeError: Can't convert re.compile('[A-Z]+') (re.Pattern) to Union[str, tokenizers.Regex]

Comment: `"[A-Z]+"` is a string and not a regex expression. `re.compile(...)` is an `re.Pattern` and not `tokenizers.Regex`. Perhaps import tokenizers.Regex from hugging face.

Comment: I have no idea where you found out about `tokenizers.Regex` because it's not in the docs, but it worked.

Comment: From the error itself. `TypeError` is an error of the `Type` of the variable. So it told you that it doesn't match `Union[str, tokenizers.Regex]`. This is called Type Hinting, `Union` means `Or`. So it was expecting a `str` or a `tokenizers.Regex`. That's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution worked by importing `Regex` from the tokenizers library:

```
from tokenizers import Regex

tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Split(pattern=Regex("[A-Z]+"),
                                behavior='isolated')
```